# how do i get an average value for scores in a table view (swift)?

Tags: swift, xcode, core-data, tableview, xcode12

I want to display an average for all values that are inputted into an Entity. Basically, one would press add on the TableView and a pop up would appear asking for a score, which would then add that “exam” to the tableview. I want to be able to add up all the scores and receive an average for them which i can then add to a label. I’ve tried following some other tutorial but it gives me an error.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/P7exB.jpg
https://i.stack.imgur.com/WWITI.jpg

The images above are for context.

```
var i = 0
var sum = 0

    for i in 0...methodsExam.count {
        let title = methodsExam[i]
        let str : String = title.value(forKey: "score") as! String
        sum = sum + Int(str)!
    }
    let avg = sum/methodsExam.count
    
    averageScore.text = "Average: \(avg)"
```

Comment: Add code instead of screenshot.

Comment: Check your loop again and read about ranges. `for i in 0...array.count` *includes* the upper bound.

Comment: I also suggest to learn how to *debug* a problem. If you get an “index out of range” error then set a breakpoint and inspect the index. Or add print statements showing the indices. You should see the problem quickly.

Comment: It's better to use a `for in` loop

Comment: @JoakimDanielson ill give that a go, thank you.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson i’m not sure what you mean, i have written for i in... is that what you were trying to say.

Comment: @PGDev yep just updated it

Comment: Sorry, I mean a for in loop without using an index. `for item in methodsExam {`

Comment: @JoakimDanielson don’t think that worked for me. could you elaborate on what you mean?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Your code would be `for score in methodsExam {}`. You should also ensure your array isn't empty

Comment: @HarryJ why would the name of the variable matter?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `methodsExam` is an array of [MethodsExam] you can change the loop to

```
var sum = 0.0
for item in methodsExam {
    if let scoreStr = item.score, let score = Double(scoreStr) {
        sum += score
    }
}
let average = sum / Double(methodsExam.count)
```

I am using Double here for more precision.

This could also be done with a high-order function

```
let average = methodsExam.reduce(into: 0.0) {
    if let scoreStr = $1.score, let score = Double(scoreStr) { $0 += score }
} / Double(methodsExam.count)
```

Since we are dividing with the array count we must also check that the array isn't empty to avoid division by 0, so we can put the code into a function and do this

```
func calculateAverage(_ array: [MethodsExam]) -> Double {
    guard !array.isEmpty else { return 0.0 }

    return  array.reduce(into: 0.0) {
        if let scoreStr = $1.score, let score = Double(scoreStr) { $0 += score }
    } / Double(array.count)
}
```

One caveat, I assumed that `score` can be nil because of MethodsExam being an NSManagedObject and not because it will hold nil values. If it indeed can hold nil values then you need to consider what to calculate the average on, all values in the array or only non-nil values.

Comment: thank you so much for this, however, no matter what i do i seem to be getting “nan” returned. am i doing something wrong?

Comment: the code for methodsExam is this:

var methodsExam : MethodsExam = []

Comment: i assume that means it’s a blank array of MethodsExam

Comment: @aadisach No that is not correct, it should be `var methodsExam : [MethodsExam] = []`. Your code should generate a complier error?